# Encrypt data with python, decrypt in php faild

Tags: python, php, encryption

I try to encrypt my data in Python and decrypt it in PHP, but when I use some data, I can decrypt it, but when I switch to some longer data, PHP fails to decrypt it. What should I do?

```
import hashlib
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode, urlsafe_b64encode, urlsafe_b64decode
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

text = 'randdata-sadkvp121kasap2l3'
secret_key = 'This is my secret lll'
secret_iv = 'This is my secret ada'

key = hashlib.sha256(secret_key.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()[:32].encode("utf-8")
iv = hashlib.sha256(secret_iv.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()[:16].encode("utf-8")

_pad = lambda s: s + (AES.block_size - len(s) % AES.block_size) * chr(AES.block_size - len(s) % AES.block_size)

txt = _pad(text)
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
output = urlsafe_b64encode(cipher.encrypt(str.encode(txt))).rstrip(b'=')
print(output) #3H-137tsFowOfREf2zekkDuL1G7gdqvRzj9BHHUCRoU
```

```
<?php

$string = '3H-137tsFowOfREf2zekkDuL1G7gdqvRzj9BHHUCRoU';
$string = base64_decode($string);
$key = substr(hash('sha256', 'This is my secret lll'), 0, 32);
$iv = substr(hash('sha256', 'This is my secret ada'), 0, 16);
var_dump(openssl_decrypt($string, 'AES-256-CBC', $key, 0, $iv));//false
```

Comment: On encryption (Python) side your ciphertext is encoded in Base64 URL-SAFE. On decryption (PHP) side you are using the regular Base64 decoding but not the URL-SAFE dependant. As the URL-SAFE just changes some characters this explains why you can decrypt some older ones and some not.

Comment: thanks,I tried to fix the encrypted string according to the encoding.It works!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$padWith = '~';
$secret = '3H-137tsFowOfREf2zekkDuL1G7gdqvRzj9BHHUCRoU';
$fixedSecret = str_replace(array('-', '_'), array('+', '/'), $secret);

$key = substr(hash('sha256', 'This is my secret lll'), 0, 32);
$iv = substr(hash('sha256', 'This is my secret ada'), 0, 16);

$decryptedSecret = openssl_decrypt($fixedSecret, 'AES-256-CBC', $key, OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $iv);
//$decrypted_secret = openssl_decrypt($decoded_secret, $method, $hashKey, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA+OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $iv_hash);

var_dump(rtrim($decryptedSecret, $padWith));//randdata-sadkvp121kasap2l3
```

Comment: `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING` disables padding and is therefore inconsistent with PKCS#7 padding in the Python code (see `_pad()`). Thus, apply `0` and also omit `rtrim()`. Btw, `_pad()` is implemented wrong and works only with characters UTF8 encoded to 1 byte (fails e.g. with §€£...), use PyCryptodome's `Crypto.Util.Padding` module instead.